# Client Credetials - how validate token?

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, client, credentials

I'm working on service to service communication. I successfully generate access token with type: client_credentials (no user context is needed). User will send this access token in header in Authorization to App1, but how can I validate this token on App1? I generate this token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token.
My goal is to validate on App1 this access token.
I've tried use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me to confirm valid of token but I'm getting always Access token validation failure.

Below the way how I generate access token and my attempt of valid this access token:
[Postman generate token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TSQL.png)
[Success response with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nCFg.png)
And I want to validate this token:
[Validate token by graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8w4s.png)

Token is generated by https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible code snippet of what you have tried so far

Comment: I've added some screens from postman. My question is how manually I could validate access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource in Postman must be set correctly to `https://graph.windows.net/`when you generate token.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjfrt.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjfrt.png]

Once you have that you should be able to query Graph no problem.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsVuO.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsVuO.png]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @maslow Did this answer you question? Id so can you mark question answered?